# Error 0x80005000 and DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to run a simple LDAP query using directory services in .Net.

```
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someserver.contoso.com/DC=contoso,DC=com");
    directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

    directorySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user) (sAMAccountName={0}))", username);

    var result = directorySearcher.FindOne();
    var resultDirectoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

    return resultDirectoryEntry.Properties["msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"].Value.ToString();
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown error (0x80005000)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

As a snippet in a Console app, this works. But when I run it as part of a WCF service (run under the same credentials), it throws the above exception.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a permission problem.

When you run the console app, that app runs with your credentials, e.g. as "you".

The WCF service runs where? In IIS? Most likely, it runs under a separate account, which is not permissioned to query Active Directory.

You can either try to get the WCF impersonation thingie working, so that your own credentials get passed on, or you can specify a username/password on creating your DirectoryEntry:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = 
    new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someserver.contoso.com/DC=contoso,DC=com", 
                       userName, password);
```

---

OK, so it might not be the credentials after all (that's usually the case in over 80% of the cases I see).

What about changing your code a little bit?

```
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
directorySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user) (sAMAccountName={0}))", username);

directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress");

var result = directorySearcher.FindOne();

if(result != null)
{
   if(result.Properties["msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"] != null)
   {
      var resultValue = result.Properties["msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"][0];
   }
}
```

My idea is: why not tell the `DirectorySearcher` right off the bat what attribute you're interested in? Then you don't need to do another extra step to get the full `DirectoryEntry` from the search result (should be faster), and since you told the directory searcher to find that property, it's certainly going to be loaded in the search result - so unless it's null (no value set), then you should be able to retrieve it easily.

Marc

Comment: I'm logged into the server where this process is running as the service account I have configured the WCF service to run as - so they are using the same credentials surely?

Comment: OK - can you step through the code (or write out trace messages) to  find out where exactly that exception happens??

Comment: The 0x80005000 is a pretty "boilerplate" error and can mean just about anything......

Answer (score 135):

I had the same again and again and nothing seemed to help.

Changing the path from `ldap://` to `LDAP://` did the trick.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. LDAP must be in caps.

Comment: great answer for me. especially if working with powershell, you are not used to case sensitive spelling

Comment: WAAAAAAAAT??! I After spending 2 hours on this LDAP solved my problem!

Comment: Weren't all MS/Windows related resources supposed to be case insensitive? Thanks.

Comment: That nailed it! I can't believe it... On top of that, when you use Url.GetComponents() in between, .net will helpfully lowercase your LDAP.

Answer (score 26):

In the context of Ektron, this issue is resolved by installing the "IIS6 Metabase compatibility" feature in Windows:

> Check 'Windows features' or 'Role Services' for IIS6 Metabase
>   compatibility, add if missing:

[image]

Ref: https://portal.ektron.com/KB/1088/

Comment: For my specific problem (hitting the OP error but I was going for IIS, not LDAP), this solved it.  Thank you

Answer (score 22):

On IIS hosted sites, try recycling the app pool. It fixed my issue.
Thanks

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thank you.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you made it. The thing is not always we have the chance to make code changes to fix an issue like this one, specially when we don't own or have the code, so trying things like this help a lot :).

Comment: If you're using an actual user account for your application pool identity and not a service account: In advanced settings for the application pool, set "Load User Profile" to True. If set to False, the registry keys needed for the COM operation will not be available if that user logs off the machine.

Comment: argh!!! this was my problem! this answer should be higher up, fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I  restarted iis after recycle.

Comment: That worked for me too! Sheesh, should have started with that. Spent hours chasing rabbits down holes :/

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error - in my case it was extra slash in path argument that made the difference.

BAD:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = 
    new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someserver.contoso.com/DC=contoso,DC=com/", 
                       userName, password);
```

GOOD:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = 
    new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someserver.contoso.com/DC=contoso,DC=com", 
                       userName, password);
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this error as well and for me it was an OU with a forward slash in the name: "File/Folder Access Groups".

This [forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4b54509f-1925-4ca2-ada5-93ca0ba6ef74) pointed me in the right direction.  In the end, calling `.Replace("/","\\/")` on each path value before use solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my problem ! After trying during 2 days fiddling about access rights, we found out an OU had been created with a slash in the name.

Comment: OMG Thank you @Nick

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI, I had the same error and was using the correct credentials but my LDAP url was wrong :(

I got the exact same error message and code

Answer (score 3):

Just had that problem in a production system in the company where I live... A webpage that made a LDAP bind stopped working after an IP changed.

The solution...
... I installed Basic Authentication to perform the troubleshooting indicated here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/329986

And after that, things just started to work. Even after I re-disabled Basic Authentication in the page I was testing, all other pages started working again with Windows Authentication.

Regards,
Acácio

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this error when I'm querying an entry of another domain of the forrest and this entry have some custom attribut of the other domain.

To solve this error, I only need to specify the server in the url LDAP :

Path with error = `LDAP://CN=MyObj,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM`

Path without error : `LDAP://domain.com:389/CN=MyObj,DC=Domain,DC=COM`

Answer (score 1):

This Error can occur if the physical machine has run out of memory.
In my case i was hosting a site on IIS trying to access the AD, but the server had run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my code from this:

```
 DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, ldapUser, ldapPassword);
 DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
 searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
 searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

To this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, ldapUser, ldapPassword);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I was trying to reference a DirectoryEntry's property value, even though that DirectoryEntry did not have that property at all.

If you for example, have:

```
var myGroup = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=mygroup,OU=mydomain....", myUsername, myPassword);

var groupManager = myGroup.Properties["managedBy"].Value.ToString();
```

If myGroup has no **managedBy** attribute set in the AD, this will result in *Unknown error (0x80005000)*

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs if in DirectoryEntry.Patch is nothing after the symbols "LDAP//:". It is necessary to check the directoryEntry.Path before directorySearcher.FindOne(). Unless explicitly specified domain, and do not need to "LDAP://".

```
private void GetUser(string userName, string domainName)
{
     DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry();

     if (domainName.Length > 0)
     {
          dirEntry.Path = "LDAP://" + domainName;
     }

     DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
     dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
     dirSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn={0})(sn={0}*)(givenName={0})(sAMAccountName={0}*)))", userName);
     var searchResults = dirSearcher.FindAll();
     //var searchResults = dirSearcher.FindOne();

     if (searchResults.Count == 0)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("User not found");
     }
     else
     {
          foreach (SearchResult sr in searchResults)
          {
              var de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
              string user = de.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
              MessageBox.Show(user); 
          }        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent a day on my similar issue, but all these answers didn't help.

Turned out in my case, I didn't enable Windows Authentication in IIS setting...

Comment: If you need to revert to the application pool user, you can do this by "expersonating" for the AD call: 
using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    /* AD-Access */
}