# Unable to connect to LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722398/error-0x80005000-and-directoryservices) that a common answer to the 0x error also covered in that aforesaid question is often to specify an account under which to search.

I realised that I'm already doing this - in fact, I'm trying to use active directory to authenticate a user to my application. Originally I thought the issue with my error related to how I was formulating my search parameter:

```
string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);
```

Where `_path` returned the URI. `domainAndUsername` returned the following:

```
"domain.com\\usrname"
```

So I changed the instantiation to:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, username, pwd);
```

returning "usr@domain.com" (*I substituted "@domain.com" because my implementation will require the user to enter their email address and NT password*).

That led me to consider the slight possibility that my test might be being performed under an account not privileged enough to perform directory searches - but I've already performed a search for the same data with another implementation - *in the same project, no less*.

So why does my implementation fall over with `0x80005000` whenever I try to use `object obj = entry.NativeObject;`?

More importantly, why does *this* implementation fall over when my original one doesn't? For reference, this implementation is using the same format as demonstrated by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx), and my original (working) implementation is below:

```
public class dirSearch
{
    public bool searchSuccessful;
    public string errStr;

    List<string> resList = new List<string>();
    public void getEmpDetails(string filStr, string varStr)
    {
        string strServerDNS = "ldap.domain.com:389";
        string strSearchBaseDN = "ou=People,o=domain.com";
        string strLDAPPath = "LDAP://" + strServerDNS + "/" + strSearchBaseDN;
        DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAPPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
        SearchResultCollection results;

        searcher.Filter = "(uid=" + filStr + ")";
        //make sure the order of the search is like so:
        //UID
        //empnum
        //full name
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(varStr);

        try
        {
            results = searcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                string temStr = result.Properties[varStr][0].ToString();
                resList.Add(temStr);
                searchSuccessful = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errStr = e.ToString();
            searchSuccessful = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Further information:**

I pulled the error code from the exception, which happened to be -2147463168. This corresponds to `ADS_BAD_PATHNAME`. This is somewhat confusing, as LDAP://ldap.domain.com:389/ is correct. My theory is that I should be using a Distinguished Name, in which case I need to return to my original working method and pull the full name of the staff member, before then formulating the name with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using anonymous authentication to login to your AD, I think you want to use username and password, then see if the user exists. Try the code below:

```
    public bool IsAuthenticated(string username, string pwd)
    {
        string strLDAPServerAndPort = "ldap.domain.com:389";
        string strLDAPContainer = "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";


        string strLDAPPath = "LDAP://" + strLDAPServerAndPort + "/" + strLDAPContainer;
        DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAPPath, username, pwd);

        try
        {
            //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
            object obj = objDirEntry.NativeObject;

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);

            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the example at the bottom of my question is the working implementation - that is, I can return an Email address, an employee number and a full name. i also tried just specifying a distinguished name, which resulted in an invalid DN syntax - the same result as your code. However, I'm not sure whether that error is down to an invalid attempt to log in, or an invalid attempt to search.

Comment: I suggest you download active directory explorer, it will give you the correct path of what you're trying to search for.